# $http get not refreshing result

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am Trying to do some examples with angularJS:

Html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <body ng-controller="JokesController">
        <h1>{{ joke }}<h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    m.factory('$jokeService', function($http, $interval) {

        var service = {
            joke: ""
        };

        service.randomize = function () {
            $http.get("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
                .success(function(data) { 
                    service.joke = data.value.joke;  
                    console.log(service.joke)
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                });
        }

        $interval(function() {
            service.randomize();
        }, 2000)

        return service;
    });

    m.controller('JokesController', function($scope, $jokeService) {
        $scope.joke = $jokeService.joke;
    });
</script>
```

The joke value is not shown in the html.
Am I missing something?

Comment: All the others have repeated the same answer and it is correct. However (THIS IS INCREDIBLY BAD PRACTICE) if you have some design architecture that wont let you modify your service and you have no other choice you can bind your service directly to the scope and it will work. `$scop.joke = $jokeService` then in your html `{{joke.joke}}`. However i strongly advise against this.

Comment: I preferred pointing out why the given scenario didn't work instead of proposing a different scenario because it shows what is going on in the code and why it doesn't work. Since the question is about some examples I don't think this will make it into production code!

Comment: I am starting to work with front end code. could you point me to the right way to do this?

Comment: Your accepted answer will work fine, but I'd suggest at least checking mine out to point you in a different direction with a more typical patterns you'll see with AngularJS development

Comment: @ste2425 The answer I have provided is valid and architecturally sound. Would you agree?

Comment: If I use that service in multiple controllers, that would generate duplicate code like setting the promise resolve function and the treatment of the response. Why is this approach better than just binding the service to the scope?

Comment: multiple controllers? Doesn't sound like duplicated code then, sounds like an object orientated approach. Perhaps you wanted to perform specific `success` logic in one controller and not the other. How would that work then? @MarcoPrado

Comment: There are actually tons of reasons why you wouldn't want to do it the way you are @ste2425 is spot on

Comment: If I just needed to access the data provided by the service then would that still be better? (I am not disagreeing with you, just trying to understand your way of thinking)

Comment: I cant edit my comment but i mean my idea is bad practice. I wasn't slating the given answers just want to make that aware. If you bind your service directly to your view you have to be careful of your view updating values in your service and those updates being propagated throughout your app. Also the separation of concerns is a good thing. However if you service only exposes read-only properties that it generates its self than it'd be ok. This is all just my humble opinion obviously.

Comment: @MarcoPrado there are cases when that could be okay, and it's subjective at that point, but when you start doing things like passing parameters and defining more functions in your services, you'll see that this approach will be more advantageous and flexible. Unit testing should benefit from this pattern as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve the factory returned promise in your controller. We can simplify your service as well by moving the resolution logic and changing injections. Observe the following change...

```
.factory('$jokeService', function($http) {
    function getJoke() {
        return $http.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random');
    }

    return {
        getJoke: getJoke
    };
});
```

---

```
.controller('JokesController', function($scope, $jokeService, $interval) {

    $interval(function() {
        $jokeService.getJoke().then(function(response) {
            $scope.joke = response.data.value.joke;
        });
    }, 2000);
 });
```

---

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/s4S8ZfAOov9n3EKwCkiS?p=preview) - working demo

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$jokeService.joke` is copied once in the controller at `$scope.joke = $jokeService.joke;`. To bind to the value that keeps changing, set `$scope.service = $jokeService` and change the binding in HTML to `service.joke`.

For your visualisation, this is what happens:

- AngularJS attempts to create the controller, but finds the service dependency
- AngularJS creates and runs the service
- AngularJS creates and runs the controller (the value gets copied here)
- The controller's scope is attached to the HTML element

Comment: is right, Remember that javascript object are the ones that get to be passed as reference not the values. You are passing the value, so the value is getting copied.